# watch controller scope variable from a sidebar directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `sidebar directive` in my web application with a set of values that bind to some model in another `controller`. When page loads, all the values are fetched and populated correctly. However when the model is updated from the controller, the event is not captured by the `watch` setup in `directive`.

Here is my `sidebar html`:

```
<div class="navbar-default sidebar" ng-controller="SettingsCtrl" role="navigation">
    <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav in" id="side-menu" style="padding-left: 8px;">
          <li ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
            <label>
              <input type="radio" ng-model="profile" name="name" value="{{profile.text}}"/>
              {{profile.text}}
            </label>
          </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

`Directive sidebar.js`:

```
angular.module('webApp')
  .directive('sidebar',['$location',function(Request) {
    return {
      templateUrl:'scripts/directives/sidebar/sidebar.html',
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, element, attrs){
        scope.$watch('profiles', function(newValue, oldValue){
          console.log(newValue + ' ' + oldValue);
        }, true);
      }
    }
  }]);
```

Here is my `SettingsCrl controller`:

```
angular.module('webApp')
  .controller('SettingsCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.profiles = [{text: "john"}, {text: "paul"}];
    function someEvent(){
        $scope.profiles.push({text: "hannah"});
    }
});
```

I have tried to do `watchCollection` instead, but still no luck..

Comment: You have a typo: `$scope.profile.push({text: "hannah"});` should be `$scope.profiles.push({text: "hannah"});`. You shouldn't need to use `$watch` to update your directive since it is prototypically inheriting from the parent scope.

Comment: @Lex fixed it. It is supposed to update, but it does not, not even a variable update is watched in my directive..

Comment: If `someEvent` is occurring outside a digest cycle you may need to wrap it in `$scope.apply();`.

Comment: `someEvent` is a `http request` call to server, which updates the `profiles` model..